# Match excel attributes to specific json items in python

Tags: python, json, excel

Here is a simplified version of the current json file i have:

```
[
  {
    "Name": "bob",
    "Age": "10"
   },
  {
    "Name": "joe",
    "Age": "17"
   },
  {
    "Name": "sally",
    "Age": "9"
   }
]
```

I also have an excel sheet that have all the information of the people, but also have their courseLoad as a separate column. I'm trying to write a python script to search through the json file for a specific name, and then pull the corresponding courseLoad for that name from my excel sheet and add it to the object. The result should look like this:

```
[
  {
    "Name": "bob",
    "Age": "10",
    "CourseLoad": "math, science, english"

   },
  {
    "Name": "joe",
    "Age": "17",
    "CourseLoad": "music, algebra, physics"

   },
  {
    "Name": "sally",
    "Age": "9",
    "CourseLoad": "computer science, knitting, PE"

   }
]
```

This is all I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import json 

file_name = "StudentInfo .xlsx"

# Load the Excel file
xl = pd.ExcelFile(file_name)


for sheet in xl.sheet_names:
    Name = xl.parse(sheet_name=sheet)["Name"]
    if Name != None: //the spreadsheet is inconsistent, sometimes the names are empty
        with open('currentStudentInfo.json') as f:
            #search through json file for the name. The methods i've seen online just brute force it using for loops, is there a more efficient way to do this? The actual file has hundreds of names, looking for a "search" or "lookup" option
            #if name is found, add the courseLoad from the excel sheet into the json item.
```

Thank you!

Comment: I love that [this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-blog/introducing-python-in-excel-the-best-of-both-worlds-for-data/ba-p/3905482) is only about a decade too late. I don't envy you

Comment: That's not JSON.  I assume there must be a reason you have removed the required syntax.  If it were me, I'd write code to "import" the JSON by converting it to a list of dictionaries, where the key is the name.  Now, you can let Python do the lookup for you.  Then, you just need an "export" function to convert it back to the shape you need.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the basic philosophy.  Use an importer to read the data into a format that is easier to process.  Read the Excel spreadsheet to update that structure.  Then write it back out.

Now, I don't know how your Excel is organized, so I don't know where you're going to find the age and courseload.  You'll have to fill that in.

```
import pandas as pd
import json 

file_name = "StudentInfo.xlsx"

# Load the Excel file
xl = pd.ExcelFile(file_name)

JSON = 'currentStudentInfo.json'
def ingest():
    data_in = json.load(open(JSON))
    data = {}
    for row in data_in:
        data[row['Name']] = row
    return data

def export(data_in):
    data = list(data_in.values())
    json.dump(data, open(JSON, 'w'))
    
students = ingest()

for sheet in xl.sheet_names:
    name = xl.parse(sheet_name=sheet)["Name"]
    if not name:
        continue
    if name not in students:
        students[name] = { 'Name': name, 'Age': 99, 'CourseLoad': [] }
    student = students[name]
    if 'CourseLoad' not in student:
        student['CourseLoad'] = []
    student['CourseLoad'].append( name['CourseLoad'] ) # or whatever

export(students)
```